# Impossible to rename a member from its id

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fivem

I am merging a bot under discord.js v12 to a newer bot with discord.js v14.

However it's my first experience on the node and I don't understand everything, I'm doing well in lua but I don't understand...

The events return me errors either it does not find the guild or it is impossible to rename a player, or a player is not found...

Here is how it is, I comment you the events according to the return of log that I have

```js
on("DiscordBot:RenameMember", (guild, discordid, fullname) => {
let targetguild = client.guilds.cache.first(); // I got on log the name of GUILD
    if (targetguild) {
        let target = targetguild.members.fetch(discordid); // I got on log : [object Promise]
        if (target) {
            target.setNickname(fullname); // I got on log : TypeError: target.setNickname is not a function
            target.member.setNickname(fullname); // I got on log : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNickname')
        }
    }
});
```

I made a multitude of tests with cache, without cache but nothing makes it all I find is similar and does not work here...

Here you will find the launch of the bot :
https://hastebin.com/ovipelopam.js

And here is the file I made separately to find my way around :
https://hastebin.com/azaraqituh.js

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `targetguild.members.fetch(discordid)` seems to return a Promise, which is an async operation. Therefore `target` has no value right away, but instead, has to either be awaited, or the rest of the code has to be put in the `then` function, that can be set to the promise.

Here is an example where you `await` the promise to resolve. In order to achieve this you have to define your function as `async`, so that it itself returns a Promise:

```
on("DiscordBot:RenameMember", async (guild, discordid, fullname) => {
let targetguild = client.guilds.cache.first(); // I got on log the name of GUILD
    if (targetguild) {
        let target = await targetguild.members.fetch(discordid); // I got on log : [object Promise]
        if (target) {
            target.setNickname(fullname); // I got on log : TypeError: target.setNickname is not a function
            target.member.setNickname(fullname); // I got on log : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNickname')
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering and explaining,
I still don't understand how it works, but it will come...
I had some problems with the setNickname and it started to work without understanding why either :)

Here is what I get in the end :

```lua
on("DiscordBot:RenameMember", async (guild, discordid, fullname) => {
    let targetguild = client.guilds.cache.first();
    if (targetguild) {
        let target = await targetguild.members.fetch(discordid);        
        if (target) {
            // target.setNickname(fullname); // I got on log : TypeError: target.setNickname is not a function
            // target.members.setNickname(fullname); // I got on log : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNickname')
            let targetRename = await target.setNickname(fullname, 'Modification correspondant au profile InGame'); // That work
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks again :)